# Create a Booklet like app in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am making a Book like app in Phonegap with Quiz... I want to keep 20 chapters for learning C. I am confused on how to use the single page architecture for such an app. I have also made a similar app for Android using JQuery Mobile and Android WebView before I was familiar with Phonegap but the application contained a number of (around 15 ) pages..and the Look & Feel was no more much native.

Any Suggestions on how to follow a single page architecture to create a book accessing its page contents from WebSQL for e.g. Chapter_title, page_heading, topic_contents ... and images if any.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of months back I was in your situation. I experimented with jquery mobile, native application and phonegap. Building a web application at first seemed very attractive at first as the coding is a lot easier compared to native applications.Even though my answer is not very specific to your question it might be helpful to others. Here is my opinion based on my research:

1. Using phonegap slows your application responses, it loads slowly and together with jquery mobile the response and load time increases. So I didnot use it.
2. Using jquery alone was no different in Gingerbread mobile and on emulator you can clearly see the lag in switching between one div to another div. I didnot use it either.
3. What I did was android Webview. I wrote my own javascript and css and placed them on the  section of my page. Used  .... for changing pages on button click. This approach worked wonders for me and gave nearly native performance.

To follow the single page architecture in html use div element as I have mentioned in step 3 above. You can write a script to convert your WebSql data to json format. Then in your page where you need to call the data using javascript parse the data. Using json in really simple.